# View Template Rendering Difference between <%= %> and <% %>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

The following is taken from page 56 of [Professional ASP.NET MVC 1.0](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/id-321793.html).

> When we look at the Details.aspx template more closely, we’ll find that it contains static HTML as well as embedded rendering code. <% %> code nuggets execute code when the view template renders, and <%= %> code nuggets execute the code contained within them and then render the result to the output stream of the template.

The statement intrinsically makes sense, but I was unable to clearly articulate to a team member exactly what it meant. A more detailed explanation of what exactly is occurring would be useful.

An example of usage from later in the chapter:

```
<% foreach (var dinner in Model) { %>
    <li>
        <%= Html.Encode(dinner.Title) %>
        on
        <%= Html.Encode(dinner.EventDate.ToShortDateString())%>
        @
       <%= Html.Encode(dinner.EventDate.ToShortTimeString())%>
    </li>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically <% %> just executes code and doesn´t output anything while <%= %> generates some form of output to the browser.

For example take <% foreach (var dinner in Model) { %>. This line just means we loop over a collection if items and there must be some matching end loop <% } %> for the page to be syntactically correct. Nothing is send to the browser because of this loop by itself.

Sending something to the browser is done using <%= Html.Encode(dinner.Title) %>. This takes the contents of the dinners Title, HtmlEncodes whatever is in there and writes it to the response stream.